# Sonar doesn't show the test coverage

Tags: java, maven, sonarqube, jacoco, jacoco-maven-plugin

My pom.xml has the below properties:

```
    <sonar.core.codeCoveragePlugin>jacoco</sonar.core.codeCoveragePlugin>
    <sonar.coverage.jacoco.xmlReportPaths>${project.basedir}/../target/jacoco.exec</sonar.coverage.jacoco.xmlReportPaths>
    <sonar.language>java</sonar.language>
    <surefire.plugin.argline>-XX:PermSize=256m -XX:MaxPermSize=1048m</surefire.plugin.argline>
```

This is what I have in my Jacoco plugin configuration:

```
<plugin>
            <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
            <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>0.8.3</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>default-prepare-agent</id>
                    <phase>initialize</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <destFile>target/jacoco.exec</destFile>
                        <propertyName>surefireArgLine</propertyName>
                        <append>true</append>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>default-report</id>
                    <phase>verify</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>report</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <outputDirectory>target/jacoco-report</outputDirectory>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <destFile>target/jacoco.exec</destFile>
                <dataFile>target/jacoco.exec</dataFile>
                <append>true</append>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

I'm using Sonar 7.8. I see the jacoco.exec file into the target folder after run:

```
mvn clean org.jacoco:jacoco-maven-plugin:prepare-agent install sonar:sonar
```

However, when I go to the Sonar page, I see how many test I have, but I only see 0% in the test coverage. Any suggestion?